# Rectify gem, mongo, tests ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mongoid5

After adding rectify gem all tests fail with error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
 No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base
```

**We are using:**
Gems:

- Rails   4.2.8
- Mongoid 5
- Rectify 0.9.1
- Rspec   3.4.4

Another:

- Os: Ubuntu 16.04LTE
- MongoDB: 3.4.3
- Database run by docker-compose.
- docker-compose version 1.12.0

Into the development mode everything works fine.
**mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        heartbeat_frequency: 10
        local_threshold: 0.015
        server_selection_timeout: 30
        max_pool_size: 5
        min_pool_size: 1
        wait_queue_timeout: 1
        connect_timeout: 10
        socket_timeout: 5
        ssl: false
        ssl_cert: /path/to/my.cert
        ssl_key: /path/to/my.key
        ssl_key_pass_phrase: password
        ssl_verify: true
        ssl_ca_cert: /path/to/ca.cert
  options:
    include_root_in_json: false
    include_type_for_serialization: false
    preload_models: false
    raise_not_found_error: false
    scope_overwrite_exception: false
    use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    use_utc: false
    log_level: debug

test:
  clients:
    default:
      database: test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        heartbeat_frequency: 10
        local_threshold: 0.015
        server_selection_timeout: 30
        max_pool_size: 1
        min_pool_size: 1
        wait_queue_timeout: 4
        connect_timeout: 10
        socket_timeout: 5
        ssl: false
        ssl_cert: /path/to/my.cert
        ssl_key: /path/to/my.key
        ssl_key_pass_phrase: password
        ssl_verify: true
        ssl_ca_cert: /path/to/ca.cert
  options:
    include_root_in_json: false
    include_type_for_serialization: false
    preload_models: false
    raise_not_found_error: false
    scope_overwrite_exception: false
    use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    use_utc: false
    log_level: debug
```

**Stacktrace**

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
    No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:501:in `create_fixtures'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:979:in `load_fixtures'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:952:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /home/user_home_directory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@testing/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:826:in `before_setup'
```

Looks like there is some simple mistake into the test database configuration but i can not figure what exactly.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rectify version 0.9.1 does not support Mongoid.
[Link](https://github.com/andypike/rectify/issues/40) to appropriate issue.